# "executable not specified" error when running python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I moved a script I was working on to another computer with the same version of python. When I try running the script on the second computer, I get an error that reads

```
error running myscript: Executable is not specified
```

Tried looking it up, didnt' seem to find anything.

Is it possible this is because I installed python alone on the first computer, but anaconda on the second? I'm not really sure what could cause the error. As far as I can tell it has nothing to do with the code. Tested on the original computer and worked fine.

Comment: What OSes are you running? How are you running the the script?

Comment: Hmm.. could it be the python executable is not in the path variable? Which operating systems are you using? Do other Python scripts work fine on the computer where you have this problem?

Comment: Windows 7. Tried double clicking it from the desktop, then running it in pycharm. I'm thinking maybe they installed anaconda after already installing python 2.7 and it messed up the install location and is still pointing to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just creating an executable through py2exe rather than trying to figure out what was going on with the paths. Works perfectly.